# Refreshing a select box onClick ( IE8 Issue )

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I am firing a click event to refresh the options of a select box when it is clicked. It works fine in FF/Chrome, but in IE I get some strange behavior. When clicked, the select box opens and closes quickly.

Here is a sample of the code

```
$(document).ready( function() {

   $(".mySelect").click( function() {
     updateOptions();
   });

});

function updateOptions() {
    var myNewOptions = "<option value='1'>Foo</option>";
    $(".mySelect").empty().append(myNewOptions);
}

<select class="mySelect"></select>
```

Comment: I doubt you want the `click` event - maybe you're looking to use the `focus` event?

Comment: I want to refresh the available options when the user clicks the select box.

Comment: Yeah, I can't even get the `click` event to register when I click one. Try using the `focus` event...it makes more sense to me. It will fire when you click on it (and it wasn't already focused)

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(".mySelect").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    updateOptions();
});
```

Looks like your click event fired twice.

Comment: Funny, I just was trying that - but still no dice :( - If it's any help - I also have a change event on the same select box. I don't see why that would matter, but thought I would point it out.

Comment: FYI, this bug is in IE8, which preventDefault is not supported in. I have also tried return false in my function.

Comment: ahh yes IE8 doesn't have `preventDefault`. try `e.returnValue = false;` instead?

Comment: @JasonWells In a jQuery handler, `preventDefault()` does not refer to what you expect. `e` refers to a custom Event object that jQuery makes for you, holding everything you need to know about the original event, in a normalized way. `e.preventDefault()` here is a normalized way to prevent the default behavior, so it's "supported" in all browsers (that's jQuery's point - browser consistency/support). You don't need to try to fix browser inconsistencies like this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   $(document).on('click','.mySelect', function(){
      updateOptions();
   })
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rUeAM/)